# Preserve query string between requests Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to learn Laravel and I got a problem I can't find a solution to.

I have a view which shows a list of items. If it gets a query parameter named userId ( ULR for example being **foo.com/?userId=1**) it shows the items owned by that user.
Also in that page I have an input for searching items with a specific name.
My problem is that I could't find a way to preserve the first query parameter (userId) when I submit the form.

I got **foo.com/?q=test** and I want to get **foo.com/?userId=1&q=test**.

I tried to add `<form action="{{ route("name.of.route", request()->input()) }}">`. It renders the route with userId parameter, but when the submit is done, it drop it and put only the q parameter..

How this can be solved in Laravel ?

If more details are needed I can provide them.

Thanks in advance.

LE: I also have pagination in the page, so the solution, I think should drop the page query parameter.

Comment: Try `http_build_query(request()->query());`.

Comment: where should I use this ? I tried with parametrised route, which i think is somehow similar with http_build_query, and didn't work. :(

Comment: Please check, what you have, on your route definitions... Isn't that you have a named parameter (userId) on your route?

Comment: Nop, it doesn't have. Route is only / , and the function bounded to this route is `public function index(Request $request)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<form action ={{Request::fullUrl()}} method="get">
.........................
          Form content here
......................
</form>
```

This will generate a form peserving the url with query so for your case it will be like this

```
<form action="foo.com/?userId=1" method ="get"> 
Some content
</form>
```

That one should do

Comment: It doesn't. Url that i got is foo.com/userId=1?q=test after submiting the form.

Comment: My bad please use `{{Request::fullUrl()}}` i updated my answer

Comment: I achieved same url using {{ route("name.of.route", request()->input()) }}, but when submiting the form, that userId parameter is gone.

Comment: why dont u create a hidden input which store the user id so when u upload the form it get also submited and u catch it from the controler?

Comment: Yeah, with this idea came to my mind today, too. But I consider it a little bit hackish. I will do this way for now, just to make it works, but I'm still open to another suggestions.